# Not able to transfer data from device to host in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have the below piece of cuda code, where I'm trying to copy back the data from device to host.

Im not able to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SLAB_SIZE 4
struct SlabList{
        int val[SLAB_SIZE];
        int key[SLAB_SIZE];
        struct SlabList* next;
};
void printList(struct SlabList *node) {
        while (node != NULL) {
                for(int i=0;i<SLAB_SIZE;i++){
                        printf("Key: %d\tValue:%d\n",node->key[i],node->val[i]);
                }
                node = node->next;
        }
}

__global__ void insertKernel(struct SlabList* SL){
        SL->key[0]=1;
        SL->val[0]=2;
        SL->next=NULL;
}
int main(void){
int N=12;
struct SlabList* d_SL = NULL;
cudaMalloc(&d_SL, N * sizeof(struct SlabList));
insertKernel<<<1,1>>>(d_SL);
struct SlabList* head = NULL;
cudaMemcpy(head, d_SL, N * sizeof(struct SlabList), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printList(head);//here head is still NULL.
return 0;
}
```

Comment: At no point have you allocated any memory for  or initialized `head`. How do you imagine the memcpy could possibly  work?

Comment: You have asked 4 CUDA questions in the last two days. All of them have been answered. As best as I can tell, you have not upvoted or accepted any of the answers. It would be good if you did both. Accepting answers increases their visibility in search and makes them easier for the next person with a similar question to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is not allocated implicitly. You have allocated an array in the GPU memory, but have not allocated it in the CPU RAM. If you want to use the variable in CPU, you need to create a new variable and allocate it.

```
...
struct SlabList* d_SL = NULL;
cudaMalloc(&d_SL, N * sizeof(struct SlabList));
struct SlabList* h_SL = NULL;

h_SL=(SlabList*)malloc(N*sizeof(struct SlabList));

cudaMemcpy(h_SL , d_SL, N * sizeof(struct SlabList), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
...
```

Note also the naming convention. `d_SL` is supposed to mean "The variable `SL`, but the version of it that its on the device (GPU)". Generally its counterpart in the CPU is called `h_SL`, or "host `SL`". It helps keeping track of variables.